# Rewrite and redirect with php variable with rewrite conditions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use rewrite rule to redirect this specific URL:
`https://example.net/?myvar=none`

to:
 `https://example.net/test-page-to-redirect/`

It's very important only redirect this specific url, because for example, this url is correct
`https://example.net/?myvar=111`

I'd tried several options without results, lastest i try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} myvar=none
RewriteRule .* /test-page-to-redirect [R=302]
```

Thanks you for your help

Comment: Do you have other directives in the `.htaccess` file? The order of directives can be important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this redirect rule:

```sh
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^myvar=none$
RewriteRule ^$ /test-page-to-redirect/? [R=302,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

By using anchors in `RewriteCond` and in `RewriteRule` we are making sure that only given URL matches nothing else.